# C++ - Invalid operands to binary expression 'basic_ostream<char>'

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I have an 'IntList' class with a dynamic array of integers, but the following fragment of test code gives me troubles:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntList.hpp"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    IntList list{};
    cout << "list-1 -> " << list << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

IntList.hpp:

```
#ifndef IntList_hpp
#define IntList_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
using std::ostream;
class IntList
{
public:
    int *dynarray;
    int capacity;
    int used;
    IntList();
    void pushBack(int x);
    int getCapacity();
    void print(ostream& sout);
};
#endif
```

IntList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntList.hpp"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ostream;

IntList::IntList()
{
    int capacity = 1;
    int used = 0;
    int *dynarray = new int[capacity];
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, const IntList& list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.used; ++i)
        sout << list.dynarray[i] << " ";
    return sout;
}
```

From what I understood, I tried to overload the << operator with this:
[invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'ostream')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029164/invalid-operands-to-binary-expression-ostream-aka-basic-ostreamchar-and)
but I don't know where I get it wrong because XCode gives me this error:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char>' and 'IntList')
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Is `ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, const IntList& list)` declared in a header?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows this error.  The problem likely exists in some code detail that isn't in your question.

Comment: @Santeau I can not reproduce.:)

Comment: Sorry, II was not careful enough, thank you for your comments, I included the code

Comment: from the code you show it is not clear if the function prototype for operator<< is in the IntList header.

Comment: I would expect `operator<<` to just say `{ list.print(sout); return sout; }`. (And `print` and `getCapacity` to be declared `const`, and the member variables to be private.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears (from the fragments you have shown) that there is no declaration of your `<<` override in the header file (`IntList.hpp`). Thus, the code in your `main` function is not (and cannot be) aware of that override, which is provided in a separate source file.

You need to add a *declaration* of that override function in the header (tyically, just after the class definition), like this:

```cpp
// Declaration (prototype) of the function for which the DEFINITION is provided elsewhere
extern ostream& operator<<(ostream& sout, const IntList& list);
```

Further, your `IntList` constructor has some serious faults. In it, you are assigning values to three ***local*** variables (whose data will be completely lost when the constructor finishes). Those variables are hiding the member variables with the same names. Use this, instead (i.e. remove the `int`  declaration specifiers):

```cpp
IntList::IntList()
{
//  int capacity = 1; // This declares a local variable that hides the member!
    capacity = 1;
    used = 0;
    dynarray = new int[capacity];
}
```

Comment: "*Further, your `IntList` constructor has some serious faults*" - the whole class is flawed, as it is violating the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It lacks a destructor to free the array, and a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to make copies of the array.